# Is there any way to restart ESX management network through python PyVmomi

Tags: esx, vcenter, pyvmomi

I am trying to restart an ESX management network through Python Pyvmomi.
Even after Google search I did not find any relevant API to do so.
Please help me if there is any API which can restart/stop ESX management network which is managed by VCentre.

Comment: Do you mean the management agent on the HostSystem?

Comment: @MichaelRice Yes probably that might also help me

Comment: Can you tell me how you would normally do what youre talking about from the user interface? That will help me figure out exactly what youre trying to do. Please let me know if its this: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003490  only you want to do it programmatically

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I want something similar, actually I want an API which will stop management network on a specific VMkernel interface, and after sometime I want to start network again. and thus I want to execute it through VCentre so that my connection won't break. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Well the answer is no this is not possible using pyvmomi. If you are open to using an SSH lib you could log onto the ESX/i server directly and do the steps in the KB article.

Comment: oh ok :( anyways thanks for conforming this Michael. May be then I will have to use SSH